# Why does Scala complain about illegal inheritance when there are raw types in the class hierarchy?

Tags: scala, inheritance, scala-java-interop, raw-types

I'm writing a wrapper that takes a Scala [`ObservableBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ObservableBuffer.html) and fires events compatible with the [Eclipse/JFace Databinding](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) framework.

In the Databinding framework, there is an abstract [`ObservableList`](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/list/ObservableList.html) that decorates a normal Java list. I wanted to reuse this base class, but even this simple code fails:

```
val list = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]
val obsList = new ObservableList(list, null) {}
```

with errors:

```
illegal inheritance; anonymous class $anon inherits different type instances of trait Collection: java.util.Collection[E] and java.util.Collection[E]
illegal inheritance; anonymous class $anon inherits different type instances of trait Iterable: java.lang.Iterable[E] and java.lang.Iterable[E]
```

Why? Does it have to do with raw types? `ObservableList` implements `IObservableList`, which extends the raw type `java.util.List`. Is this expected behavior, and how can I work around it?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but does it work when the list is parameterized by an object instead of a primitive?  (E.g. `ArrayList[String]` or `ArrayList[java.lang.Integer]`?)

Comment: No, I still get the same errors.

Comment: I'm no expert in Scala, but why are you using the curly braces in the initialization of `ObservableList`? Isn't this some kind of a partial function? In Java that would be inheritance, but why would you want to inherit it?

Comment: `ObservableList` is abstract but with no abstract methods. I need the curly braces to instantiate an anonymous subclass.

Comment: Do you hava a pointer to the javadoc of ObservableList? I googled, but found various different ones

Comment: @Jens: I've added in in the question.

Comment: In the (temporary?) absence of a way to deal with this problem in Scala, I wrote a custom subclass in Java which I can then use from Scala. Not very nice, but it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a Java raw type in the inheritance hierarchy causes this kind of problem.  One solution is to write a tiny bit of Java to fix up the raw type as in the answer for  [Scala class cant override compare method from Java Interface which extends java.util.comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329001/scala-class-cant-override-compare-method-from-java-interface-which-extends-java-u)

For more about why raw types are problematic for scala see this bug http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1737 . That bug has a workaround using existential types that probably won't work for this particular case, at least not without a lot of casting, because the java.util.List type parameter is in both co and contra variant positions.

Answer (score -2):

From looking at the javadoc the argument of the constructor isn't parameterized.

I'd try this:

```
val list = new java.util.ArrayList[_]
val obsList = new ObservableList(list, null) {}
```

Comment: Something like `new ParametrizedType[_]` has never worked (neither does `new Thing<?>` in Java); it doesn't compile.