# Examples of Java frameworks which don't play well with Scala

Tags: java, scala, frameworks

Has anybody run across a Java/Java EE framework which causes problems if used with Scala?

Comment: I'm hoping for no answers to this one ;)

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of the question? Could you explain a bit, why do you need this information? Pure curiosity?

Comment: Well, I would like to know if you have to give up on any of the frameworks by switching to Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know of a specific one, but any pre-Java 5 framework that uses raw types may cause trouble at some point in Scala, especially if you have a raw type in the hierarchy of a class you must implement. Here are a few questions related to this issue:

- [Implementing methods having raw types in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279149/implementing-methods-having-raw-types-in-scala)
- [Why does Scala complain about illegal inheritance when there are raw types in the class hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991671/why-does-scala-complain-about-illegal-inheritance-when-there-are-raw-types-in-the)
- [Scala class cant override compare method from Java Interface which extends java.util.comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329001/scala-class-cant-override-compare-method-from-java-interface-which-extends-java-u)

Answer (score 1):

The was a [problem](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Bug-illegal-cyclic-reference-involving-class-Document-td2400516.html) for a while with JSoup hitting a [bug](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3809) in Scala, making typical JSoup usage broken in Scala without writing a bit of extra Java. Interestingly, the JSoup developers altered JSoup to avoid this bug, so current versions integrate smoothly. I'm not sure if the Scala bug responsible is fixed yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Commons-CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli) won't work in Scala (at least, not if you use their OptionBuilder class).  The reason is that the [OptionBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.html) uses static methods, and then has you call them via an instance.  Javac will let you get away with that (it's at worst a warning), but scalac won't find the static methods.  It looks for them on the instance, but they're not there. From scala's perspective, they'd be on the companion object, but that's not what you have.